# ActiveRecord query is not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, activerecord, facebook-fql

I'm using Koala api to query Facebook.

```
@result = @graph.fql_query("select uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE is_app_user AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())")
```

I'd like to discard some instances of the object @result by querying my ActiveRecords "Shoot":

```
@result.each do |f3|
     y1 = Shoot.where(:uid1 => f3["uid"])
     @y2 = y1
     if y1
       xtUid = f3["uid"]
       xName = f3["name"]
       xPicture = f3["pic_square"]
       ....
     end
     ...
end
```

I have the following problem. It seems that:
1. y1 is always set as valid but the program doesn't crash
2. If I replace y1 by y1[0], the program crashes.

I'd appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Comment: In addition in the rails console y1 behaves correctly

Comment: It probably means the `where` brings back nothing, an empty array. Trying to access the first element crashes everything. Log your SQL requests to make sure they should bring back something

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto But it seems that y1 produces true. If "Where" brings back nil, wouldn't if y1 produce false? Thanks!

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto You are right it brings back nothing. But I can't figure out why. In addition if it brings back nothing, why then does "if y1" produce true? Also xUid, xName and xPicture get the correct values. Thanks again!

Comment: `where` never returns nil. If nothing is found, you'll an empty array. If you `if y1`, you'll get `true` since it's an object. Maybe you were looking at `Shoot.find`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer: f3["uid"].to_s. F3["uid"] needs to be converted into a string. Thanks @Anthony for helping!